# jQuery selector doesn't work very well for Polymer2 shady dom template

Tags: jquery, polymer-2.x, shady-dom

my company using Bootstrap Tour which works perfectly fine with PolymerV1, but after updated to PolymerV2 shady dom version. The jQuery selector doesn't work very well. For example: if using this way:

// configurationId is auto generated for this element

```
$('#title-Checklist-'+configurationId+'-name') // doesn't work
$('title-Checklist-382757-name') // doesn't work too
```

However, if using:

```
$('[id=title-Checklist-' + configurationId + '-name]')[0]; // it works
```

I have tried other selectors such as:

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector,
document.getElementById
this.$.title-Checklist-configurationId-name
...
```

All doesn't work! Does any one know what the difference between two? or Any better solution for using jQuery in Polymer2 shady DOM?

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter can't tell the difference between strings and variables in:

```
$(#title-Checklist-configurationId-name)
```

Try this:

```
$('#title-Checklist-'+configurationId+'-name')
```

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you so much for response! Actually, I typed wrong in description, just corrected it. I just used exactly as your way : $('#title-Checklist-'+configurationId+'-name'), event I put $('#title-Checklist-382757-name') couldn't select element. It shows r.fn.init and _prop_: object(0). but this way works: $('[id=title-Checklist-' + configurationId + '-name]')[0];  for me it doesn't make any  scene, do you have any idea?

Comment: That's strange. I'm not all that familiar with Bootstrap. I wish I could help you more.